# Why does the scrollTo method inside RecyclerView not have any effect?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a LinearLayoutManager set to horizontal. As you can see in the code below, I am trying to animate from the first item of the list to the last item of the list using ValueAnimator. In my usage, I don't need to use the scrollBy or scrollToPosition methods. I need to use the scrollTo method, but it has no effect. Why is this the case?

```
ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,activityMainBinding.rv.computeHorizontalScrollOffset());
valueAnimator.setDuration((100000)); valueAnimator.setStartDelay(1500);
valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator1 -> { 
activityMainBinding.rv.scrollTo((int) valueAnimator1.getAnimatedValue(), 0); });
valueAnimator.start();
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example of the bug?  Have you tried using print statements to determine whether any values are returning unexpected outputs?  Does the issue persist when you remove lines of code?  It is difficult to determine what might be causing this issue when there are so many things in play, like the .getAnimatedValue function the .setDuration bit, the .setStartDelay bit, etc.

Comment: @gabetucker22 I built a new project to test this method with simple recyclerview but the same result, method not scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look inside of *RecyclerView*, you will see the following for `scrollTo()`:

```
@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
    Log.w(TAG, "RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position. "
            + "Use scrollToPosition instead");
}
```

In fact, you should see that text in your logcat.

You say that you must use `scrollTo()`, but that doesn't seem possible. I suggest that you review this requirement to understand why `scrollTo()` is required.

I will also suggest that *RecyclerView#computeHorizontalScrollOffset()* is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: [Look at this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW80S.png), I'm trying to move scroll from first to last. But I'm confused what math should I use to make it working with ValueAnimator. I tried `activityMainBinding.activityMainRecyclerViewNewsTicker.scrollBy(horizontalThumbOffset / totalLengthOfCharacters, 0);` but did not working and result will be float but scrollBy accept int params only. also I think scrollToPosition method will not be useful for my usage.

Comment: If you are going to pursue `scrollBy()` then let me suggest that you try to get a simple version working with just a scalar quantity. Once you can do that, then introduce the animation, offset calculation, etc. The biggest challenge, IMO, will be to get `scrollBy(1000)` or some other number working.

Comment: I think there is also a `scrollBy()` in _LinearLayoutManager_, if that's what you're using, that you may be able to do something with.